# How to maximize webapp height on iPhone with CSS? (hide URLbar properly)

Tags: iphone, html, css

Here's my problem. On an iPhone, how can I set the container/viewport high enough to hide the URLbar but still not higher than the available document area.

If I just set the container (which also has overflow: hidden) to height: 100%, this is the result:
http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/9041/img0027g.png

ie. the container becomes only the height of the visible document area. However, hiding the URLbar requires the document to be at least as high as the available document area (URLbar scrolled up).

This is what I'm after:
http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/2613/img0029nv.png

I know I can do this with JavaScript (innerWindow height) but I would prefer pure CSS solution.

Comment: What's wrong with the JavaScript method?

Answer (score 0):

force a minimum height so the page can scroll

```
body[orient="portrait"] { min-height:540px; }
body[orient="landscape"] { min-height:400px; }
```

or if it is a web app on homescreen it is even simpler.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```